# How to auto update a record in database?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-update

I have a jobs table in which I inserts new jobs.
This table also contains the job post date.

By default the job status is open when a new insertion take place.

Now I want to change the status of the job from open to close when the jobs becomes older than 30 days.

How will I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a event which runs every day like below

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
  ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  DO
    UPDATE my_table SET status ='closed'
    WHERE post_date > DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
    AND status='open'
```

-- Update Changed syntax

```
  CREATE EVENT myevent
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR
  DO
    UPDATE my_table SET status ='closed'
    WHERE post_date > DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
    AND status='open'
```

Comment: Where should I wrote the above query? In Mysql's SQL tab?

Comment: yes and use `SHOW events from DbName` to see if event has been created

Comment: The query execute successfully and now it shows the event which I created. But how will check the date and time of the event that on which date and time it was executed last?

Comment: Try this query `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'myevent' AND EVENT_SCHEMA = 'DbName'`

Comment: Hi, I have created an event yesterday as you described in your answer but it did not update the status column to closed when I view it today. I use the select query mentioned in your comment, there the last execution time of the event is NULL.

Comment: use this command to check if event scheduler is on `SELECT @@event_scheduler;` if it is not activated `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;`
You’ll also have to add: event_scheduler=ON
To the /etc/my.conf in the [mysqld] section . also check my updated answer this syntax is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cron job to handle this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

If you can't handle crons, you could do a "poor man's cron". Means the actual process that updates all of your jobs records takes place when someone visits your page (with additional checks when the last run was). If you're doing it the "poor" way I suggest to fire off another thread to keep your site responsible.

Comment: But how will be the crontab file? Can you tell me the content of that file and with which extension should I save that file?

Comment: http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html. Today I learned that mysql supports events, so I'd stick with the solution from Naveen.