# How to update whole record of database after one month or one year automatically?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am developing a web application for a bank.
I am going to maintain loan details and installment of loan and installment
of loan and loan balance should be maintain automatically month wise.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Cleanest way is using ETL (extract transform load). Now it depends what technology you are willing to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9583470/2901207 might be duplicate

Comment: In Oracle you can use job.